# Dining Philosopher Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing

This is my code:

Table.java

```
public class Table {
    Lock mutex; 
    int nbrOfChopsticks;
    private boolean chopstick[]; //true if chopstick[i] is available

    public Table(int nbrOfSticks){
        nbrOfChopsticks=nbrOfSticks;
        chopstick=new boolean[nbrOfChopsticks];
        for(int i=0;i<nbrOfChopsticks;i++){
            chopstick[i]=true;
        }
    }

public synchronized void getLeft(int n) throws InterruptedException{
    //philosopher n picks up its left chopstick
    chopstick[n] = false; 
}

public synchronized void getRight(int n) throws InterruptedException{
    //philosopher n picks up its right chopstick
   chopstick[n] = false; 
}

public synchronized void releaseLeft(int n){
    //philosopher n puts down its left chopstick
    int pos = n + 1;
    if (pos == nbrOfChopsticks) {
        pos = 0;
    }
    chopstick[pos] = true;
}

public synchronized void releaseRight(int n){
    //philosopher n puts down its right chopstick
    int pos = n + 1;
    if (pos == nbrOfChopsticks) {
        pos = 0;
    }
    chopstick[pos] = true;
}


}
```

Philisopher.java

```
   public class Philosopher implements Runnable{
      private int id;
      private Table myTable;

      public Philosopher(int pid,Table tab){
          id=pid;
          myTable=tab;
      }

      @Override
      public void run(){
           for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
               try {
                 //think
                 System.out.println("Philosopher " + id + " thinks. Iteration "+ i);
                 Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*100));
                 //pick up chopsticks
                 System.out.println("Philosopher " + id + " pick up left");
                 myTable.getLeft(id);
                 Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*10));
                 System.out.println("Philosopher " + id + " pick up right");
                 myTable.getRight(id);
                 //eat
                 System.out.println("Philosopher " + id + " eats. Iteration "+ i);
                 Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*100));
                 //release chopsticks
                 System.out.println("Philosopher " + id + " drop left"); 
                 myTable.releaseLeft(id);
                 Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*10));
                 System.out.println("Philosopher " + id + " drop right");
                 myTable.releaseRight(id);
             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(Philosopher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }           
          }
       }
    }
```

I am completely unable to spot when the so-called: deadlock occurs in my code. I've been trying to figure it out when it occurs, with no result. I am also implementing wait() & notify() and lock unlock calls.

If someone knows this better than me, please tell me. I appreciate all of your help. Thanks a lot in advanced.

**EDIT: Updated the code as one sir here required me to do.**

**3nd EDIT: This is my output.**

Philosopher 0 thinks. Iteration 0

Philosopher 4 thinks. Iteration 0

Philosopher 3 thinks. Iteration 0

Philosopher 2 thinks. Iteration 0

Philosopher 1 thinks. Iteration 0

Philosopher 1 pick up left

Philosopher 1 pick up right

Philosopher 1 eats. Iteration 0

Philosopher 1 drop right

Philosopher 1 drop left

Philosopher 1 thinks. Iteration 1

Philosopher 4 pick up left

Philosopher 4 pick up right

...

---

Any help on this code is appreciated. If someone can explain to me, I'd really appreciate your help and the stuff you teach me.

New modification of code:

```
public synchronized void getRight(int n) throws InterruptedException {
        //philosopher n picks up its right chopstick
        int pos = n + 1;
        if (pos == nbrOfChopsticks) {
            pos = 0;
        }

        while(!chopstick[pos]){
            wait(); 
        }

        chopstick[pos] = false;
    }
```

**Adding wait(); and notify(); to the code makes it *LAG*, see screenshot:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG2ni.jpg

Comment: Have you tried a debugger? Also, using random id(s) like that is probably causing your deadlock (randomly).

Comment: Yes, I've tried everything. For the record, I am self-learning as I am not even in college yet.

Comment: Can someone confirm if my code as a whole is correct, or are you guys able to spot something wrong. Recall, I am still learning these things on my own pretty much. I appreciate your input.

Comment: You should always release resources in the order acquired, I note you getLeft(), then getRight() and then releaseLeft() and then releaseRight(). Swap the order of the release statements.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch is that the only thing wrong?

Comment: @ErikEriksson No idea, just something I spotted. Another one is `mutex.lock();` in `releaseLeft()` should be `mutex.unlock()`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "You should always release resources in the order acquired"--I assume you meant "the reverse order"?

Comment: @ajb Yes. Thank you. *You should always release resources in the **reverse** of the order acquired,*

Comment: @ajb what do you guy's mean by "reverse order", I did swap them as you told me earlier. Thanks!

Comment: The `getLeft`/`releaseLeft`, `getRight`/`releaseRight` logic seems to be broken. `*Left` should operate on the `n`th fork, `*Right` on the `n+1`th.

Comment: @xxa You mean I shall change it, chopstick[n] = false;  n + 1 in the case of the right method?

Comment: @ErikEriksson: for philospher `n`, the left chopstick is `chopstick[n]`, the right one is `chopstick[(n+1) mod N]`, where `N` is the number of philosphers. `get` and `release` should be consistent with this on both sides.

Comment: @xxa What about my releaseLeft() releaseRight() methods? Thanks for spotting this, I must have miscalculated.

Comment: @ErikEriksson see my answer with details

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62403/discussion-on-question-by-erik-eriksson-dining-philosopher-java). @xxa I moved it to chat for you.

Comment: Are you aware of the [21 other Java “Dining Philosopher” questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+is%3Aquestion+Dining+Philosopher)?

Comment: Yes, and I have already solved this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//if none are available perform a wait(); 
while (!chopstick[n] || !chopstick[pos]) {
    wait();
}
```

That solved it.

**One has to check if none are available, this way you know that both chopsticks are currently under use, and therefore you can invoke Java's wait() method and keep on waiting for a free chopstick regardless of right or left. This helps avoid a potential deadlock.**

Answer (score 2):

Since you are a self-learner, I'll give you some hints and leave the full implementation as an exercise.

It seems that locks and mutexes are new to you. Have you ever heard about the *talking stick*? When a bunch of people gather together in a circle, you put a stick in the middle. Whenever one wants to share their opinion, they grab the stick. Only the person who holds the stick is allowed to speak. They speak, and then they put the stick down, so someone else is allowed to speak.
This is a lock. Only, instead of people and sticks, there's Locks/Monitors and threads.

The idea is simple: grab the lock (`mutex.lock()`), do whatever you have to do (acquire / release / wait for chopstick), and then release the lock again (`mutex.unlock()`). Your `Table` is missing this last step. Usually, this kind of problem follows the following pattern:

```
public void actOnSharedState() {
    mutex.lock();
    try {
        // Do whatever you have to do, here.
    } catch (SomeExceptionThatMightOccurException ex) {
        // Handle it appropriately.
    } finally {
        // You always give the lock back, even
        // when an exception occurs. This is important!
        mutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

In your specific case, there are some flaws in the code's logic.

1. Your `getRight` is supposed to acquire the chopstick, but it is releasing it instead (`chopstick[pos] = true`).
2. Your `releaseLeft` is acquiring, instead of releasing (`chopstick[n] = false`).
3. You don't need to `wait` in order to release your left chopstick.
4. Use either `synchronized` or the `Lock`. They achieve the same, with different methods, in this particular problem. Use `mutex.signal`, instead of `notify`, and `mutex.await`, instead of `wait`, if you opt for the Lock.

If you follow the above pattern, and fix these points, you should be ready to go. Note that, when using a single lock, instead of a lock per chopstick, you **must** *acquireLock-doAction-releaseLock*, otherwise only one philosopher will be picking sticks at a time, and you won't get the deadlock (no concurrency).

It may not be easy to experience the deadlock, but there's an interleaving (order of actions by the various threads) where it is possible. For 3 threads, for instance:

1. Thread 1 picks left stick.
2. Thread 2 picks left stick.
3. Thread 1 waits, Thread 2 already has Thread 1's right stick.
4. Thread 3 picks left stick.
5. Thread 2 waits, Thread 3 already has Thread 2's right stick.
6. Thread 3 waits, Thread 1 already has Thread 3's right stick.
7. Deadlock, everyone waits indefinitely.

---

**Update:** based on the updates on your question, here are a few more notes.

1. Your `releaseLeft` is actually releasing the right chopstick. Change it to the following.

   ```
   public synchronized void releaseLeft(int n){
       //philosopher n puts down its left chopstick
       chopstick[n] = true;
   }
   ```
2. You don't need to wait to release, but you **should** wait to acquire a chopstick, if it is unavailable, and you should notify waiting philosophers when you put a chopstick down. This applies to both the left and right chopsticks, remember to fix both.

   ```
   public synchronized void getLeft(int n) throws InterruptedException {
       //check if chopstick is available
       while (!chopstick[n]) {
           wait();
       }
       //philosopher n picks up his left chopstick
       chopstick[n] = false; 
   }

   public synchronized void releaseLeft(int n) {
       //philosopher n puts down his left chopstick and notifies others
       chopstick[n] = true;
       notifyAll();
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I am trying to figure things out. Please see my Edit and give me your input.

Comment: I added, mutex.unlock(); to my release function, this is now causing exceptions, I am completely confused.

Comment: @ErikEriksson I've updated my answer. I think it now includes everything you need to fix.

Comment: I just can't wrap my head around this?

Comment: while (!chopstick[n]) {
        wait();
    }

Shall I make it n + 1 in the right methods? I am confused here.

Comment: Like this:


public synchronized void getRight(int n) throws InterruptedException {
        //philosopher n picks up its right chopstick
        int pos = n + 1;
        if (pos == nbrOfChopsticks) {
            pos = 0;
        }
        
        while(!chopstick[pos]){
            wait(); 
        }
        
        chopstick[pos] = false;
    }

Comment: can you confirm to me if my edit is correct or not, as I am very confused, especially, by various responses and answers. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know why the code might LAG now that I added wait() notify() to it? (It completely freezes now???)

Comment: @ErikEriksson Yes, you should follow the `int pos = n + 1; if (pos == nbrOfChopsticks) { pos = 0; }` rule for the right chopstick. Also, my bad, it should be `notifyAll`, instead of `notify`. The lag is expected, since the philosophers weren't waiting before (two philosophers using the same stick simultaneously), and, in the end, you want it to lag so much that nothing happens (deadlock).

Comment: So this is the DeadLock that I am experiencing here?

Comment: It makes sense, so what would be the perfect step to make this deadlock free

Comment: @ErikEriksson You now understand that, if everyone picks their left chopstick, there will be a deadlock, because no one can pick their right chopsticks. Their right chopsticks are the left chopsticks of the next guy, so they wait eternally. To make it deadlock-free, it requires the philosophers to put down the left chopstick if they can't acquire the right chopstick, so the guy to the left has a chance to use it. Since this requires significant (enough) changes to the code, I suggest posting another question if you run by any problems.

Comment: It does require code edit to the Philisopher.java, but how do I check and enforce. What you are saying makes sense, thanks a lot @afsantos.

Comment: Weird, so the code works now perfectly, I am confused, I haven't even modified the Philisopher.java code yet. Weird. No explanation of how.

Comment: @ErikEriksson How to do it is a nice problem for another question. The guidelines would be to remove the wait on the right chopstick, and have it return success or failure. Then making the philosopher react accordingly. It is possible for this code to work. Threads aren't predictable. Deadlock is only a possibility, occurring when certain conditions (order of operations) are met.

Answer (score 2):

There may be other issues, but the assigment of chopsticks to philosphers is not consistent with regard to get/release operations: Instead of

```
public synchronized void getLeft(int n) throws InterruptedException{
    //philosopher n picks up its left chopstick
    chopstick[n] = false; 
}

public synchronized void getRight(int n) throws InterruptedException{
    //philosopher n picks up its right chopstick
   chopstick[n] = false; 
}

public synchronized void releaseLeft(int n){
    //philosopher n puts down its left chopstick
    int pos = n + 1;
    if (pos == nbrOfChopsticks) {
        pos = 0;
    }
    chopstick[pos] = true;
}

public synchronized void releaseRight(int n){
    //philosopher n puts down its right chopstick
    int pos = n + 1;
    if (pos == nbrOfChopsticks) {
        pos = 0;
    }
    chopstick[pos] = true;
}
```

it should be:

```
public synchronized void getLeft(int n) throws InterruptedException{
    //philosopher n picks up its left chopstick
    chopstick[n] = false; 
}

public synchronized void getRight(int n) throws InterruptedException{
    //philosopher n picks up its right chopstick
    int pos = n + 1;
    if (pos == nbrOfChopsticks) {
        pos = 0;
    }
   chopstick[pos] = false; 
}

public synchronized void releaseLeft(int n){
    //philosopher n puts down its left chopstick
    chopstick[n] = true;
}

public synchronized void releaseRight(int n){
    //philosopher n puts down its right chopstick
    int pos = n + 1;
    if (pos == nbrOfChopsticks) {
        pos = 0;
    }
    chopstick[pos] = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see. But how can I fix the lock() & unlock() for this, I've been trying out for hours now with no result. You sir are kind. ;-)

Comment: @ErikEriksson I'm sorry, but I don't quite see what you are referring to. Locking/unlocking is taken care of by the `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: Not as far as I understand it, this Lock mutex; Did you see @afsantos answer?

Comment: @ErikEriksson Yes, I agree with his advice "4. Use either synchronized or the Lock". In this case `synchronized` is all you need.

Comment: @ErikEriksson Well, this is hard, but I suggest to study the concept in general (see for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html), and of course try to run the code to see if it works as expected

Comment: See my latest edit, I added my latest output in this code, is it correct if you follow this output? Thanks a lot sir.